# What does Redim(array) accomplish?

Tags: excel, vba, windows

Since an array can be written to without knowing its size, why does it need to redimensioned after the split?

```
Array = split( string)
REDIM Array(0 to Ubound(array))
```

What does the REDIM accomplish?

Comment: This is necessary to be done when (initially) you do no know the necessary array dimensions. For instance, you load an array from a range with variable number of rows and you want processing it in memory, for having a really fast code. So, you need to `ReDim` the array where the result to be loaded. Now, you cannot name an array variable as `Array`. It already means something from VBA... You may have `Dim arr1, arr2`. Then `arr1 = Split("My sister has a pet")`. Then you can use `ReDim arr2(ubound(arr1))` if needed. Or use it as a maximum, fill it by iteration and finally use `ReDim Preserve`.

Comment: My understanding is that arrays use dynamically allocated memory. Changing the array dimensions requires allocating more/less memory to accommodate the new dimensions. That's the main purpose of Redim. It's interesting that in your example (if you used a valid array name, as @FaneDuru noted), the Redim statement would simply delete all array elements while retaining the same dimensions as the result of the Split() statement. The Split statement handles allocating the array, so it has already been set to 0 To Ubound.

Comment: what is this code? - from where is this code? - what does it try to accomplish? - your going into this with a wrong assumption (there doesn't need to be a Redim, why would you think it was required?

Comment: In the limited example you have given, the array does not need to be redimensioned, and REDIM accomplishes nothing. In most real code examples where an array is redimensioned, it is necessary.